# Building a Tilemap in Python/Pygame and testing for mouse position

Tags: python, grid, pygame, mouse

Hey i appreciate any help you can provide

I am creating a tile-map for a test of a possible project. I have found a tutorial which produced the tile-map effectively. I then tried to implement my own code by making it loop through each X and Y coordinate testing if the mouse is in the position of the block. If the mouse was positioned on top of the tile a box would be drawn on it to create a visual for where the mouse was. The problem i have is that the grid was made to look like this:

```
                                    ####
                                    ####
                                    ####
                                    ####
```

But the mouse detection only works diagonally on these tiles:

```
                                    ####
                                     ###
                                      ##
                                       #
```

The code is below:

```
    from pygame.locals import *
import pygame, sys

green = (40,255,30)
brown = (40,60,90)
red = (155,20,30)
yellow = (0,155,155)

grass = 0
dirt = 1
lava = 2

colours = {
    grass: green,
    dirt: brown,
    lava: red,
    }

tilemap = [
        [grass,dirt,dirt,dirt, lava],
        [dirt,lava,dirt,dirt, dirt],
        [lava, grass,dirt,dirt, lava],
        [lava, grass,dirt,dirt, grass],
        [dirt,dirt,dirt,dirt,grass]

        ]

TILESIZE = 50
MAPWIDTH =  5
MAPHEIGHT = 5

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE,MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE))

while True:


    mouse_x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
    mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit
        for row in range(MAPWIDTH):
            print
            for column in range(MAPHEIGHT):
                pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, colours[tilemap[row][column]], (column*TILESIZE, row*TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
                if mouse_x >= (row * TILESIZE) and mouse_x <= (row* TILESIZE) + TILESIZE:
                    if mouse_y >= (column * TILESIZE) and mouse_y <= (column* TILESIZE) + TILESIZE:
                        print (str(row) + " " + str(column))
                        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, yellow, (row * TILESIZE, column*TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))







    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you're not clearing the screen.
Next your draw code is wrong (wrong if checks) 
The correct is x for columns and y for rows.

I hope that this could help you! :)

```
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame, sys

green = (40,255,30)
brown = (40,60,90)
red =  (155,20,30)
yellow = (0,155,155)

grass = 0
dirt = 1
lava = 2

colours = {
    grass: green,
    dirt: brown,
    lava: red,
    }

tilemap = [
        [grass,dirt,dirt,dirt, lava],
        [dirt,lava,dirt,dirt, dirt],
        [lava, grass,dirt,dirt, lava],
        [lava, grass,dirt,dirt, grass],
        [dirt,dirt,dirt,dirt,grass]

        ]

TILESIZE = 50
MAPWIDTH =  5
MAPHEIGHT = 5

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE,MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE))
```

while True:

```
    mouse_x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
    mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]

    print mouse_x, mouse_y

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        DISPLAYSURF.fill((0,0,0));
        for row in range(MAPWIDTH):
            print            
            for column in range(MAPHEIGHT):
                color = colours[tilemap[row][column]];
                if mouse_x >= (column * TILESIZE) and mouse_x <= (column* TILESIZE) + TILESIZE:
                    if mouse_y >= (row * TILESIZE) and mouse_y <= (row* TILESIZE) + TILESIZE:
                        print (str(row) + " " + str(column))
                        color = yellow;                                                                                                            

                pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, color, (column*TILESIZE, row*TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))


    pygame.display.update()
```